# How to optimize promises to avoid callback/promise hell

Tags: node.js, express, promise, callback, knex.js

I'm using knex.js for my database and I have a query that depends on the previous query.

Example:

user table

| username(pk) | first_name | last_name |

login table

| username(pk/fk) | hash |

Process is:

Insert to user > insert to login

login is dependent on user, so it will return an error if the insert to user is not yet finished.

This is my code:

```
const handleSignup = (req, res, db, logger, bcrypt) => {
    const {
        username,
        password,
        firstName,
        lastName,
    } = req.body;
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
    if (username || !firstName || !lastName ) {
        res.json({
            haveEmpty: true
        });
        return;
    } else {
        db.transaction((trx) => {
                db.select('*').from('user').where('username', '=', username)
                    .then(data => {
                        if (!data[0]) {
                            db('user')
                                .returning('*')
                                .insert({
                                    username: username,
                                    first_name: firstName,
                                    last_name: lastName,
                                })
                                .then(user => {
                                    db('login')
                                        .returning('*')
                                        .insert({
                                            username: username,
                                            hash: hash
                                        })
                                        .then(login => {
                                            if (login[0]) {
                                                res.json({
                                                    isSuccess: true
                                                });
                                                return;
                                            } else {
                                                res.json({
                                                    isSuccess: false
                                                });
                                                return;
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .then(trx.commit)
                                        .catch(err => {
                                            logger.error(err);
                                            trx.rollback;
                                            res.render('pages/error-500');
                                        });
                                })
                                .then(trx.commit)
                                .catch(err => {
                                    logger.error(err);
                                    trx.rollback;
                                    res.render('pages/error-500');
                                });
                        } else {
                            res.json('User already Exist!');
                            return;
                        }
                    })
                    .then(trx.commit)
                    .catch(err => {
                        logger.error(err);
                        trx.rollback;
                        res.render('pages/error-500');
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => logger.error(err));
    }
}
```

And I do not know if I'm using transactions right. But this is what I've come up. Before, when I separate the query into two promises, I get an error because it seems that the first insert (user) is not finishing.

This code is working, but I know that there's a more correct way to code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, promises start to feel much more natural once you stop trying to cram 'em all into the same function! (But all of us have probably written something similar to your example at one time or another, don't worry.)

Smaller chunks of code have a tendency to be easier to test and debug too. For example, if you know that your check on the variables in the request body is correct, then perhaps the problem lies further down the stack.

Here's an example using a small middleware stack. This allows breaking the operations up into bite-sized chunks, while still guaranteeing that one thing will happen before the other.

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const express = require("express");
const knex = require("knex");
const config = require("./knexfile").development;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const db = knex(config);

const detailValidator = (req, res, next) => {
  // You can do more robust validation here, of course
  if (!req.body.firstName || !req.body.lastName) {
    return next(new Error("Missing user details."));
  }
  next();
};

const userUniqueValidator = (req, res, next) => {
  db("users")
    .where("username", req.body.username)
    .then(users => {
      if (users.length !== 0) {
        return next(new Error("User exists."));
      }
      next();
    });
};

const userCreator = (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);

  db.transaction(trx =>
    trx("users")
      .insert({
        username,
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName
      })
      .then(([userId]) => trx("auth").insert({ user_id: userId, hash }))
      .then(() => res.json({ success: true }))
  ).catch(err => next(err));
};

app.post("/", detailValidator, userUniqueValidator, userCreator);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => res.json({ error: err.message }));

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("yup"));
```

Regarding transactions in Knex: you don't actually need to call `commit` at all, if using the above syntax. You do need to use the `trx` argument as a query builder, however. The documentation also suggests another option, which is the `transacting` syntax: see [docs](https://knexjs.org/#Transactions).

Finally, I wouldn't really recommend using your username as a primary key. They're too often required to change, and there's always the risk of accidentally leaking one in a URL or log. I would recommend including a unique constraint, however. Something like this perhaps?

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable("users", t => {
    t.increments("id");
    t.string("username").unique();
    t.string("first_name");
    t.string("last_name");
  });

exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable("auth", t => {
    t.increments("id");
    t.integer("user_id").references("users.id");
    t.string("hash");
  });
```

It's worth noting that I used SQLite3 for this quick example, which only supports returning a row id after inserts (hence the `[ userId ]` in the `then` clause after user insertion).

Comment: Plus 1 for this - Chopping things into small bits like this also allows you to (more) easily test each bit individually, so you don't get as lost when the thing never works the first time. :)

Comment: My only concern in this is that, how can I use those small chunks of function on another file-script? Because what I do is, I tend to separate each of them on their own file so that my main server.js will not become too large.

Comment: You can put them wherever you like. I only put everything in one 'file' as an example. Because Express middleware always has the same signature, you can write boring old JS functions which do something with the data in `req` or `res` before passing control via `next`. Then just import/require the ones you need in your stack for a particular route.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a Promise inside the then callback will execute the promises one after the other as so:

```
const handleSignup = (req, res, db, logger, bcrypt) => {
    const {
        username,
        password,
        firstName,
        lastName,
    } = req.body;
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
    if (username || !firstName || !lastName) {
        res.json({
            haveEmpty: true
        });
        return;
    }

    db.transaction((trx) => {
        db.select('*').from('user').where('username', '=', username)
            .then(data => {
                if (data[0]) {
                    res.json('User already Exist!');
                    return;
                }

                return db('user')
                    .returning('*')
                    .insert({
                        username: username,
                        first_name: firstName,
                        last_name: lastName,
                    });
            })
            .then(user => {
                return db('login')
                    .returning('*')
                    .insert({
                        username: username,
                        hash: hash
                    });
            })
            .then(login => {
                if (!login[0]) {
                    res.json({
                        isSuccess: false
                    });
                    return;
                }

                res.json({
                    isSuccess: true
                });
            })
            .then(trx.commit)
            .then(trx.commit)
            .then(trx.commit)
            .catch(err => {
                logger.error(err);
                trx.rollback;
                res.render('pages/error-500');
            });
    })
        .catch(err => logger.error(err));
}
```

The thing I'm not 100% sure about your code is the fact that you'll only be rolling back the last query and not all of them. Keep an eye on this.